# How to custom swipe like this

Tags: android

I custom listview with swipe, i using lib :
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView
But i cant handle when click icon like then change image like this:

[image]

When click on heart shape then change like this.
What is lib or way can do so?
Thank you!

Comment: It's better if you use this [lib](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout). SwipeMenuListView is deprecated

Comment: Thanks you, it work for me <3